# Jquery select right element using next()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im trying to get to the right element by next() but still didnt do it right ;/

```
                <li class="menu">
                    <ul>
                    <li class="button"></li>
                    <a href="#manifest"><li class="menu_glowne">MANIFEST</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

I want to get to the .button by mouseover .menu

```
$('.menu').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).next("li").animate({'opacity':1},500);
});
```

How i can make it? My code doesn't work.

Comment: Use `$(this).find("li.button")` instead.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation for `.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)? It makes it pretty clear that `.next()` doesn't do a search through the DOM, it returns the immediately following sibling or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You need [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/), next is used to get siblings whereas find will look for descendants.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bCPfh/)**

```
$('.menu').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find("li").animate({'opacity':1},500);
});
```

Edit, there are few errors in html structure as well.

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu"> Menu
        <ul>
            <li class="button">button</li> <a href="#manifest">manifes</a>t<li class="menu_glowne">MANIFEST</li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.menu').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find("li").animate({'opacity':1},500);
});
```

Should work fine :)

Comment: Not exactly, the OP wants to have the ".button" not the ".menu_glowne". So one should use either `$(this).find("li.button")` or `$(this).find("li").first()` (in this case). The first method is more accurrate. Cheers.